# Format color in python for converting Blender model to .xaml

Tags: python, xaml, colors, formatting, blender

```
# Formats a color
def formatColor(self, color):
    return "#%.2x%.2x%.2x" % (color.r*255, color.g*255, color.b*255)
```

This method is a part of Blender addon for exporting model to xaml. When I try to run conversion Blender returns an [image: error] which says "%x format an integer is required not float". I thought that .2 is a problem here so tried to modify formatter like this

```
"#%0x%0x%0x"
```

but error persists. Blender uses python 3.5 so I tried to replace it with 3.4 and it doesn't help either. With python 2.7 latest Blender does not even starts. 
I also tried this

```
int(color.r*255)
```

and this

```
int(round(color.r))*255
```

but an error is always the same.

How could I modify this method such that it returns an integer not float?

Comment: `color = C.active_object.material_slots[0].material.specular_color; print("#%.2x%.2x%.2x" % (int(color.r*255), int(color.g*255), int(color.b*255))` in blender python console works fine for me. Converting to int before multiplication is unlikely to produce desired result.

Comment: @keltar it works. thanks. now I have xaml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody will use this [plugin](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=xamlexporter). After casting in such a way conversion to xaml works fine for python 3.5.

```
"#%.2x%.2x%.2x" % (int(color.r*255), int(color.g*255), int(color.b*255))
```